# How should I read values automatically into Matplotlib's aitoff projection from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I have looked around for the answer for around 2 weeks now and I cannot seem to find any help. Basically I'm trying to read in values (2 columns to be exact) from a csv file. Here's an example:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('TGAS_2MASS_ALLWISE_TYC2.csv', delimiter = ', ', usecols=['ra','dec'])
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4.2))
plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")
plt.title("Aitoff")
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(my_data, 'o', markersize=2, alpha=1)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=1,bottom=0.0)
plt.show()
```

I have tried many different ways to make this work, but I can't seem to find any. Here's the error it gives me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-da402c9f65a8> in <module>()
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from numpy import genfromtxt
----> 6 my_data = genfromtxt('TGAS_2MASS_ALLWISE_TYC2.csv', usecols=['ra','dec'], delimiter = ',')
      7 plt.figure(figsize=(8,4.2))
      8 plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows)
   1626             # if usecols is a list of names, convert to a list of indices
   1627             if _is_string_like(current):
-> 1628                 usecols[i] = names.index(current)
   1629             elif current < 0:
   1630                 usecols[i] = current + len(first_values)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: Can you show what your csv file looks like?

Comment: 210.0079259734,-52.3214149846,-99999.,0,10,0.62,0.45,11.53,85,-2.449,0.497,-8.341,1.28,6089270560571566592,5.058319010332389E-4,14000190-5219171,11.066,10.993,10.944,0.022,0.021,0.021,AAA,J140001.90-521917.0,10.89,10.916,10.842,9.355,0.023,0.022,0.084,0.483,0000,0,AAAC,11.961,11.736,210.0079097665295,-52.32140478043333

This is one of the lines. There are thousands more.

Comment: Always create a [mcve] of the issue. Please also read [ask]. Here it is unimportant that you want to plot the data, the problem comes from the genfromtxt line. Hence you can leave everything else out. **But**, the error depends on reading in some data, so you need to provide a minimal dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on how the csv file looks like. But even if it has column names

```
ra, tum, dec, mor
1, 2, 3, 5
2, 4, 5, 3
2, 1, 4, 3
```

you can still read it in using `usecols=[0,2]`. The documentation states:

> `usecols` : sequence, optional
>   Which columns to read, with 0 being the first. For example, usecols = (1, 4, 5) will extract the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns.

Hence you cannot use strings as columns, but integer numbers instead.

```
u = u"""ra, tum, dec, mor
1, 2, 3, 5
2, 4, 5, 3
2, 1, 4, 3"""

import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt


my_data = genfromtxt(io.StringIO(u), delimiter = ', ', usecols=[0,2])

plt.plot(my_data, 'o')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

According to what I understand, `plt.plot` will take 2 mandatory arguments `(x, y)` representing the data in x and y axes. `x` and `y` here are lists of values (float or int), and have the same length. So I think `plt.plot(my_data, 'o', markersize=2, alpha=1)` in your code is wrong. Your `mydata` is n-times-n matrix, so many matpltolib is trying to say it cannot plot given the data is >3 dimensions?

Comment: No, matplotlib can plot any `n` x `m` array. It will then take the first `n` integers as `x` and plot `m` different lines. Try it out: `plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10,3))`.

Comment: Yes! Obviously I am wrong! Sorry for not being so helpful!

Comment: If you find that an answer you provided does not help or does not address the issue, you may of course edit it to answer the question, or delete it after all.